# ruby setting variable versus using variable

Tags: ruby

I'm somewhat new to ruby so there may be an easy solution to this.

But basically I want to reuse an object @result, so that when I execute a method on it (`filter`) I continue to be using the original object. However, as I run the method, the object itself seems to be changing.

The object (@result) is RDF::Query::Solutions class
http://rdf.rubyforge.org/RDF/Query/Solutions.html#filter-instance_method

```
@result = rdf_query(query) # solutions object
```

At this point the @result contains all the solutions, approximately 30 results

```
@pubinfo = @result.filter(:ptype => RDF::URI("http://scta.info/pubInfo"))
```

At this point @result becomes equivalent to what I want only @pubinfo to be. There are only 5 or so results

```
@contentinfo = @result.filter(:ptype => RDF::URI("http://scta.info/contentInfo"))
```

at this point @contentinfo comes up `nil` because the filter is actually on the solutions left from the previous filter. But i wanted to run this filter on the original contents of @result

```
@linkinginfo = @result.filter(:ptype => RDF::URI("http://scta.info/linkingInfo"))
```

Again predictable the @linking is 'nil' because @result was set to `nil` in the previous filter. But I don't want @result changing.

Please help.

## update

Look what happens if i try the following

```
@pubinfo = @result
@pubinfo2 = @pubinfo.filter(:ptype => RDF::URI("http://scta.info/pubInfo"))
binding.pry
```

At this point @result = has been filtered. Why should should @result be affected at all by what I do to @pubinfo. In other words, how do i make @pubinfo a mere copy or duplicate of @result so that one is not affected by the other??

Comment: `filter` seems to be a destructive method (it is an alias to `filter!`) to it changes the object itself

Comment: That's seems like a correct analysis to me - any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: create a new `rdf_query` per filter?

Comment: seems inefficient -- three requests to the database -- when all the information I need is already in the first query

Comment: I agree... I'm not familiar with this library, does it have `clone`? or `dup`?

Comment: If `filter` is destructive, and you need to access the original value (pre-`filter`ing) then you don't have much of a choice except to re-query, dupe/clone, or find a non-destructive alternative.

Comment: It looks like "filter" refines the query.  Can you use another method that executes the query and acts on the retrieved records?  Say @pubinfo = @result.select{|r|r.ptype == RDF::URI("http://scta.info/pubInfo")}

Comment: Ok thanks everybody -- adding @result.dup.filter seems to work great!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation:

> This method returns an undefined value.
>
> Filters this solution sequence by the given criteria.

This is quite vague, I agree, but one thing stands out - it returns an `undefined value`, from this I conclude that this is a destructive method, which changes the current object rather than returns a new object with the result of the filter. Another hint to this is that it is `Also known as: filter!`, since methods ending in `!` are by convention destructive in ruby.

Looking at the source code verified this conclusion, as it uses `reject!` in the code.

As to solutions on how to do it properly - I'm not familiar with this library, and it has proven quite hard to try and figure it out from the documentation, I suggest you find a way to do one of the following (ordered from most recommended, down to last fallback):

1. Find a non-destructive API
2. Find a `dup` or `clone` API
3. Re-query before each `filter`...

And maybe try to contact the author to provide his own recommendation...